# How to create subgroups of a fixed number of subjects out of a large group?

Tags: random

I am analyzing data from an experiment composed of 60 subjects. Every subject made a decision which is numerical. I need to create groups of 3 subjects out of the 60, so that at the end I will have 20 groups of three and then take the decisions of each group member and calculate the sum of the value of their decisions, according to the group membership.

I have tried this code which works in reshuffling the group:

```
students=1:60;
rand_students=sample(students,length(students));
```

But I need not only to reshuffle them but to pick their decision and then calculate their average by group

Comment: Please specify the programming language and framework you're using in the tags

Answer (score 0):

It s unclear what programming language you are using. I will use R, but the general concept should be transferable to other languages as well.

I suggest to keep all the data for your students not in separate vectors but in one compound table. In R this would be a `data.frame` or one of its derivatives. With such a tabular structure, it is easy to aggregate results based on certain criteria. this can be done using base R, though I prefer packages like `dplyr` or `data.table`:

```r
set.seed(42)
library(data.table)
# put ID and decision in one structure
student_data <- data.table(id = 1:60,
                           decision = runif(60))
# assign random group by adding a new column with group ids
student_data[, group := sample(rep(1:20, 3))]
# aggregating the decision by group
student_data[order(group), mean(decision), by = group]
#>     group        V1
#>  1:     1 0.3620594
#>  2:     2 0.4908625
#>  3:     3 0.6767199
#>  4:     4 0.2572053
#>  5:     5 0.4437264
#>  6:     6 0.8668130
#>  7:     7 0.4014190
#>  8:     8 0.3104299
#>  9:     9 0.6696232
#> 10:    10 0.4790010
#> 11:    11 0.7365284
#> 12:    12 0.7964717
#> 13:    13 0.7549513
#> 14:    14 0.3553608
#> 15:    15 0.6076658
#> 16:    16 0.8211349
#> 17:    17 0.6680640
#> 18:    18 0.6844966
#> 19:    19 0.4591455
#> 20:    20 0.5640735
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Great, it worked perfectly thanks. And Yes I use R, sorry for not being precise.

Comment: @mondilla You are welcome. Please consider accepting or upvoting the answer if it was helpful.